# Function to print command-line usage for a program

Tags: python, strings

The following function works well to print out a help message for the program I have written. It prints a multi-line string message that describes the command line usage with some examples:

```
def usage():

    print(
        """
Usage examples:

Test deployment:
       $ fab [noinput] test deploy

Staging deployment:
       $ fab [noinput] staging deploy

Production deployment:
       $ fab [noinput] production deploy
""")
```

Unfortunately, in order to make the message look good in the output, the code block currently looks ugly with the string message making the indentation of the code look wrong. Is there a way to improve the code so that it is more readable, similar to the following code (which does not work - it is just an example) where the indentation is more readable?

> ```
> def usage():
>
>     print(
>         """
>         Usage examples:
>         Test deployment:
>             $ fab [noinput] test deploy
>         Staging deployment:
>           $ fab [noinput] staging deploy
>         Production deployment:
>           $ fab [noinput] production deploy
>         """
>     )
> ```

How can the readability be improved while still producing results that look good in the output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412374/python-triple-quote-multi-line-indentation

Comment: This is being [discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8852/31503)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to remove common whitespace from the start of all lines in a multiline string:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print(textwrap.dedent(
        """
        Usage examples:
        Test deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] test deploy
        Staging deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] staging deploy
        Production deployment:
            $ fab [noinput] production deploy
        """
))

Usage examples:
Test deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] test deploy
Staging deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] staging deploy
Production deployment:
    $ fab [noinput] production deploy
```

As it says in the docs:

> This can be used to make triple-quoted strings line up with the left edge of the display, while still presenting them in the source code in indented form.

Answer (score 23):

For smaller pieces of text, I tend to just close the double quotes and open them on the next line. Then you'll have to add the newlines yourself using `\n` though:

```
print(
    "Usage examples:\n"
    "Test deployment:\n"
    "    $ fab [noinput] test deploy\n"
    "Staging deployment:\n"
    "    $ fab [noinput] staging deploy\n"
    "Production deployment:\n"
    "    $ fab [noinput] production deploy\n"
)
```

Comment: If you don't like adding '\n' in each string, you can also do `print(
    "Usage examples:",
    "Test deployment:",
    "    $ fab [noinput] test deploy",
    …, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 19):

When I need some usage-text or help-text about a program or module, there is another option, at the begin of the source code:

```
#!/bash/python  
"""  
Usage examples, Test deployment,  
and any other text you like  
"""
```

And when I need to print it somewhere in the program:

```
print(`__doc__`)
```

Answer (score 8):

Also you may want to use `.join()` method:

```
def usage():

    print('\n'.join([        
        'Usage examples:',
        'Test deployment:',
        '    $ fab [noinput] test deploy',
        'Staging deployment:',
        '    $ fab [noinput] staging deploy',
        'Production deployment:',
        '    $ fab [noinput] production deploy'        
        ]))
```