# Small CLI note manager and publisher

Tags: python, git

This is my first attempt at trying to make a CLI note manager, than can be easily published on the web. I have made one note and you can see it live [here](http://lekhakpadmanabh.github.io/).

I have added some comments, and placed the function `cli_parse` to the bottom (for readability). The way I wanted it work is for it just create markdown files with my notes, in a pre-initialized git repository. After the note has been saved, it asks git for the files that have been changed since last commit, and puts all their content into a JSON file which is simply passed to the webpage.

```
import subprocess
import os
import json
import markdown2
import argparse
import re
from datetime import datetime
from slugify import slugify
import codecs


class GitHandler:
"""
changed_files() looks at all markdown files in notes/
directory, and returns them so that content.json file
can be reupdated.
"""

    def __init__(self,repo_path):
        self.repo_root = self.set_repo(repo_path)

    def set_repo(self,repo_path):
        repo_path = os.path.abspath(repo_path)
        if os.path.exists(repo_path):
            if os.path.isdir(repo_path):
                if os.path.exists(repo_path+'/.git'):
                    return repo_path
                else:
                    print """Repository doesn't exist. 
                    Follow the instruction in README."""
            else:
                print "Provide path to your repo directory"
                return None
        else:
            print "Path Does Not Exist"
            return None

    def add(self):
        subprocess.call(['git','add',self.repo_root + '/notes/'])

    def commit(self,message):
        subprocess.Popen(['git','--no-pager','commit','-m',message])

    def changed_files(self):
        return subprocess.check_output(['git','diff','--name-only',
                'HEAD']).split('\n')[:-1]


class Note:

    def __init__(self,title,content,tags=[],
            date=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")):
        self.title = title
        self.content_raw = content
        self.content = self.md_to_html(content)
        self.id = None
        self.tags = tags
        self.date_created = date

    def md_to_html(self, text):
        return markdown2.markdown(text, extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])

    def __str__(self):
        return """
#{0}

{1}

Posted on {2}
Tags: {3}
""".format(self.title,self.content_raw,self.date_created, ",".join(self.tags or [])).encode('utf-8')

class NoteDB:
"""
For CRUD operations on json file
"""

    def __init__(self):
        #self.note = self.note_to_dict(note)
        self.data = self.get_db()

    def get_db(self):
        if os.path.isfile("../data.json"):
            json_data = codecs.open("../data.json",encoding='utf-8')
            # This is giving an 
            try:
                data = json.load(json_data)
                json_data.close()
                return data
            # VERY EXPERIMENTAL-- CHECK IOT OUT
            except:
                return "{}"
        else:
            author = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
            blog_title = raw_input("Blog title: ")
            content = {
                "Blog Title": blog_title,
                "Author": author,
                "count": 0,
                "notes": [],
                "pages": []
            }
            self.write_data(content)
            return content

    def write_data(self,data):
        data['count'] = len(data['notes'])
        with codecs.open("../data.json",encoding='utf-8',mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(data,f,ensure_ascii=False)

    def new_id(self):
        try:
            lngth = len(self.data['notes'])
            maxid = max([note['id'] for note in self.data['notes']])
            return max( lngth, maxid)
        except ValueError:
            return 0

    def note_to_dict(self,note):
        return {
            "id": self.new_id(),
            "title": note.title,
            "content": note.content,
            "tags": note.tags,
            "date_created": note.date_created
        }

    def all_entries(self):
        for note in self.data['notes']:
            print "{0} -- {1}".format(note['id'],note['title'])

    def get_entry(self,id):
        for note in self.data['notes']:
            if note['id'] == id:
                return note
        print "Error"

    def post_entry(self, note):
        titles = [n['title'] for n in self.data['notes']]
        if isinstance(note, Note):
            if note.title not in titles:
                self.data['notes'].append(self.note_to_dict(note))
                self.write_data(self.data)
            else:
                print "----------"
                for i,n in enumerate(self.data['notes']):
                    if note.title == n['title']:
                        print "----------"
                        self.data['notes'][i] = self.note_to_dict(note)
                        self.write_data(self.data)
        else: 
            print "Error: must be a note object"

    def put_entry(self,note):
        print "Not implemented"

    def delete_entry(self):
        print "Not implemented"


def inline_note(title,body,tags):
        """
        creates a markdown file with content supplied
        and saves it appropriate filename in notes/
        """
        if title and body:
            nt = Note(title,body,tags)
            ndb = NoteDB()
            ndb.post_entry(nt)
            #make sure file doesn't exist in notes/
            file = open(slugify(title)+'.md','w')
            file.write(str(nt))
            file.close()
        else:
            print "Title and body are required. Tags are optional."

def new_note(title, tags):
    """
    Opens new file with title supplied in default 
    text editor with title, tags and date added to the 
    file.
    """
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    text = "#{0}\n\nCreated on {2}\nTags:{1}".format(title,tags,date)
    filename = slugify(title)+'.md'
    f = open('../notes/'+filename,'w')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
    os.system('{0} {1}'.format('xdg-open', '../notes/'+filename))

def parse_md(filename):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    s = f.read()
    f.close()
    title = re.findall(r'#(.+)\n',s)[0]
    tags = re.findall(r'Tags:(.+)',s)[0].strip().split(',')
    date = re.findall(r'Created on (.+)',s)[0].strip()
    body = re.findall(r'\n([^#].*)Created on', s, re.S)[0].strip()
    return title,body,date,tags

def build():
    """
    Walks through changed files in notes/ and
    updates the content.json file accordingly
    """
    git = GitHandler(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
    git.add()
    git.commit("Gitnote commit")
    changed_files = git.changed_files()
    for filename in changed_files:
        if filename[-3:] == '.md':
            filename = '../' + filename
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                print "-----"
                title,body,date,tags = parse_md(filename)
                nt = Note(title,body,tags,date)
                ndb = NoteDB()
                ndb.post_entry(nt)

def cli_parse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('mode')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--body')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--title')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--tags')
    return vars(parser.parse_args())


def dispatch_method(args):
    if args['mode'] == "inline":
        inline_note(args['title'],args['body'],args['tags'].split(','))

    elif args['mode'] == "new":
        new_note(args['title'],args['tags'])

    elif args['mode'] == "build":
        build()

    else:
        print("Doesn't compute. Please type cli --help for usage")

dispatch_method(cli_parse())
```

Usage:

```
"""
Usage: 

1. New note in text editor:

  >> gitnote new --title "Hello gitnote" --tags "python,angular,github, git"
  >> gitnote build
  >> git push origin master

First command opens "hello-gitnote.md" in your default editor. The title, date and tags have already been entered for you.
Second command updates the json file (db)
Third command deploys to github


2. Inline note:

  >> gitnote inline --body "hello world" --title "this is the title" --tags "hello,world"
  >> gitnote build
  >> git push origin master

First command creates a new file called hello-world.md in notes/
Second command updates the json file (db)
Third command deploys to github
"""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), your imports should look like:

```
import argparse
import codecs
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os
import re
import subprocess

import markdown2
from slugify import slugify
```

---

Also per the style guide, there should be a single space between arguments to functions, in the definition *and* the call (or at least *be consistent*):

```
date = re.findall(r'Created on (.+)',s)[0].strip()
                                   # ^ no space here...
body = re.findall(r'\n([^#].*)Created on', s, re.S)[0].strip()
                                        # ^ ...but space here?
```

There should also be two blank lines between `class` definitions.

---

None of your classes or methods have any explanation as to what they're doing - consider adding in [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

---

Multiline strings like:

```
        return """
#{0}

{1}

Posted on {2}
Tags: {3}
""".format(...)
```

can be made neater with `textwrap.dedent` - see e.g. [Avoiding Python multiline string indentation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60366/32391). It breaks up the "flow" of the code to see something on the left margin in an instance method definition.

---

Don't just `print "Error"` if something goes wrong - [`raise` an `Exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions). In terms of error handling, a bare `except:` is [a bad idea](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/); handle specific errors (or at least `Exception`).

---

You can use this guard to prevent your code running if you later decided to `import` functionality from it to some other script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dispatch_method(cli_parse())
```

It might make the code easier to read if `dispatch_method` and `cli_parse` were the last two functions defined.

---

I doubt that:

```
def inline_note(title,body,tags):
    if title and body:
```

does what you think - there will be a `TypeError` if too few arguments are supplied. This only guards against e.g. `inline_note("", "", ("a tag",))`. Maybe use something like:

```
def inline_note(title, body, tags=None):
```

to indicate that `tags` is optional?

Answer (score 2):

A pet peeve of mine is to use
[ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson), essentially speed for free.

I'd rather use less nested ifs, e.g. for the `set_repo` function, but
really for all those cases:

```
def set_repo(self, repo_path):
    repo_path = os.path.abspath(repo_path)

    if not os.path.exists(repo_path):
        print "Path Does Not Exist"
        return

    if not os.path.isdir(repo_path):
        print "Provide path to your repo directory"
        return

    if not os.path.exists(repo_path+'/.git'):
        print """Repository doesn't exist.
        Follow the instruction in README."""

    return repo_path
```

For variable names, I doubt `lnght` buys you much vs. the more readable
one character longer word.

To add to the error handling, I think you should use the `check_`
functions all the time, so that your program doesn't go ahead if
e.g. the `git add` failed.

`get_db` should be split into two functions (and possibly a wrapper):
one to load the database (`load_database`?) and one to create it
(`create_database`).  The loading call can also use the `with`-statement to
ensure the closing of the file.