# Travelling salesman using brute-force and heuristics

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

I have implemented both a brute-force and a heuristic algorithm to solve the travelling salesman problem.

```
import doctest
from itertools import permutations


def distance(point1, point2):
    """
    Returns the Euclidean distance of two points in the Cartesian Plane.

    >>> distance([3,4],[0,0])
    5.0
    >>> distance([3,6],[10,6])
    7.0
    """
    return ((point1[0] - point2[0])**2 + (point1[1] - point2[1])**2) ** 0.5


def total_distance(points):
    """
    Returns the length of the path passing throught
    all the points in the given order.

    >>> total_distance([[1,2],[4,6]])
    5.0
    >>> total_distance([[3,6],[7,6],[12,6]])
    9.0
    """
    return sum([distance(point, points[index + 1]) for index, point in enumerate(points[:-1])])


def travelling_salesman(points, start=None):
    """
    Finds the shortest route to visit all the cities by bruteforce.
    Time complexity is O(N!), so never use on long lists.

    >>> travelling_salesman([[0,0],[10,0],[6,0]])
    ([0, 0], [6, 0], [10, 0])
    >>> travelling_salesman([[0,0],[6,0],[2,3],[3,7],[0.5,9],[3,5],[9,1]])
    ([0, 0], [6, 0], [9, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5], [3, 7], [0.5, 9])
    """
    if start is None:
        start = points[0]
    return min([perm for perm in permutations(points) if perm[0] == start], key=total_distance)


def optimized_travelling_salesman(points, start=None):
    """
    As solving the problem in the brute force way is too slow,
    this function implements a simple heuristic: always
    go to the nearest city.

    Even if this algoritmh is extremely simple, it works pretty well
    giving a solution only about 25% longer than the optimal one (cit. Wikipedia),
    and runs very fast in O(N^2) time complexity.

    >>> optimized_travelling_salesman([[i,j] for i in range(5) for j in range(5)])
    [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
    >>> optimized_travelling_salesman([[0,0],[10,0],[6,0]])
    [[0, 0], [6, 0], [10, 0]]
    """
    if start is None:
        start = points[0]
    must_visit = points
    path = [start]
    must_visit.remove(start)
    while must_visit:
        nearest = min(must_visit, key=lambda x: distance(path[-1], x))
        path.append(nearest)
        must_visit.remove(nearest)
    return path


def main():
    doctest.testmod()
    points = [[0, 0], [1, 5.7], [2, 3], [3, 7],
              [0.5, 9], [3, 5], [9, 1], [10, 5]]
    print("""The minimum distance to visit all the following points: {}
starting at {} is {}.

The optimized algoritmh yields a path long {}.""".format(
        tuple(points),
        points[0],
        total_distance(travelling_salesman(points)),
        total_distance(optimized_travelling_salesman(points))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The multiline string could be neater - see e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60366/32391. Also, you could remove the very long test line by either including a slice (e.g. check every 5th item from it) or having a separate (multiline) assignment so you can compare the result of the function to the list as `>>> result == expected` then just `True`.

Comment: `optimized_travelling_salesman` feels like a misnomer to me, probably should be `greedy_travelling_salesman`

Comment: Quite interesting code, esp. because of its simplicity. I also checked it against my standard TSP algo and it issues indeed the shortest path. What I don't get is the "optimized" path. Applied to your 'points it is only 8% longer but you say it can be up to 25% longer. Well, the algo may be faster but what's **optimizing** about it?

Comment: @Apostolos running time is optimized, it is a simple heuristic (practical shortcut) to always go to the nearest city to save computational time. The  route is only a bit longer but runnning time is drastically shorter

Comment: Yes, this is clear. But my question is if the route obtained is 25% longer, what's the use of the heuristic algo? And then, how do you mean "dramatically"? Can you give a **percentage** of time reduced and the **size** of the data sample that you used  for testing time?  (It's also OK if can't or don't wish to! :)

Comment: @Apostolos to get an approximate idea consider that 20 factorial is  2.432902e+18 while 20^2 = 400. So while the brute-force algoritm that take time proportional to N! is only viable up to 12 (12! = 479001600 ~ half a billion) or something cities, because the factorial skyrockets like crazy, the optimized one that runs in time proportional to N^2 can handle up to 10000 (10000^2 = 10^8 long but feasible). So it can handle tremendously more cities while only making the route ~25% longer according to wikipedia

Comment: I see. I got a little dizzy but it's OK ... :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I enjoyed the first look at the code as it's very clean, you have
extensive docstrings and great, expressive function names.  Now you know
the deal with PEP8, but except for the one 200 character long line I
don't think it matters much really.

There're a few typo with the wrong spelling "algoritmh".

The coordinates should be immutable 2-tuples.  The reason being the
safety of immutable data-structures.  YMMV, but that makes it really
obvious that those are coordinates as well.

`optimized_travelling_salesman` should make a defensive copy of
`points`, or you should otherwise indicate that it's destructive on that
argument.

Instead of `if start is None: start = points[0]` you could also use
`start = start or points[0]` to save some space while still being
relatively readable.

For the algorithms the only thing I'd is not to use square root if you
don't have to.  You can basically create a `distance_squared` and use that
instead of `distance` because the relationship
between a smaller and bigger distance will stay the same regardless.
That doesn't apply for the final output of course. Edit: And, as mentioned below by @JanneKarila, you can't use that for the brute-force version.

Comment: Result will be different using the sum of squared distances. \$1+3 = 2+2\$ but \$1+9 > 4+4\$

Answer (score 3):

Besides thanking you for posting this, I wanted to share how I edited your code to do something I needed.

I'm implementing a survey for econ research. Part of the implementation is giving our survey team a list of addresses so that they can visit them. After geo-coding these addresses, we organized them into neighborhoods through a very simple k-means clustering process. Each member of our team is assigned a zone, therefore we needed to provide them with an optimized route within each zone.

The issue at hand was that members of our survey need additional data on top of the location data - such as unique IDs for households and basic contact info for the household. So, somehow I needed to keep some form of identification for each coordinate so I could merge it back with the relevant data.

I realize this might be a simple edit, but I couldn't figure out another way to have a relation between the two tables of data.

The code is exactly the same, except for that it returns an enumerated list (enumerated at the time of input) so that you can merge it back with other data.

I also added a haversine formula for calculating the distance between two geo-coordinates in miles.

```
import numpy as np
def haversine_enum(item1, item2):
    """
    Returns the great-circle distance between two enumearted points
    on a sphere given their indexes, longitudes, and latitudes in the
    form of a tuple.

    >>> haversine_enum((0, (3,5)), (1, (4,7)))
    154.27478490048566

    >>> haversine_enum((0, (41.325, -72.325)), (1, (41.327, -72.327)))
    0.17282397386672291
    """
    r = 3959 #radius of the earth
    r_lat = np.radians(item1[1][0])
    r_lat2 = np.radians(item2[1][0])
    delta_r_lat = np.radians(item2[1][0]-item1[1][0])
    delta_r_lon = np.radians(item2[1][1]-item1[1][1])

    a = (np.sin(delta_r_lat / 2) * np.sin(delta_r_lat / 2) +
        np.cos(r_lat) * np.cos(r_lat2) *
        np.sin(delta_r_lon / 2) * np.sin(delta_r_lon / 2))

    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1-a))

    d = r * c

    return d

def optimized_travelling_salesman_enum(points, start=None):
    """
    Taken from:
        https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81865/
        travelling-salesman-using-brute-force-and-heuristics

    As solving the problem in the brute force way is too slow,
    this function implements a simple heuristic: always
    go to the nearest city.

    Even if this algoritmh is extremely simple, it works pretty well
    giving a solution only about 25% longer than the optimal one (cit. Wikipedia),
    and runs very fast in O(N^2) time complexity.
    """

    points = list(enumerate(points))
    if start is None:
        start = points[0]

    must_visit = points
    path = [start]
    must_visit.remove(start)

    while must_visit:
        nearest = min(must_visit,
                       key=lambda x: haversine_enum(path[-1], x))
        path.append(nearest)
        must_visit.remove(nearest)

    return path
```

Comment: @Toby Speight > how it improves upon the original: 'it returns an enumerated list (enumerated at the time of input) so that you can merge it back with other data.'

Comment: Very reasonable solution, the enumeration looks simple, otherwise maybe you could have built a dictionary putting in relation the coordinates as keys to the informations as values